# My Cs50 problem set 2 code has a problem with random letters going blank. How can i fix it?

Tags: c, cs50

sorry if i dont use the correct terminology but i am new to coding and i just started cs50 and i really like it! But currently i am stuck at problem set 2(caesar). My code works (kinda) i mean its good for 90% of cyphering but there are some blank letters above key 10 and i dont want to do. I would appreciate your help and excuse my newbie mistakes!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool check_valid_key(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2 || !check_valid_key(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    {
        string text = get_string("plaintext:");
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        {
            if(text[i]>='a' && text[i]<='z')       
            {          
                text[i] += key;
                while(text[i]>'z')
                {
                    text[i]-= 26;
                }
            }
            if(text[i]>='A' && text[i]<='Z')
            {         
                text[i] += key;
                while(text[i]>'Z')
                {
                    text[i]-= 26;
                }
            }
        }      
        printf("ciphertext:%s\n", text);
        return 0;
    }       
}

bool check_valid_key(string s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
             return false;
        }        
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This probably wasn't done intentionally, but please remove excess newlines.

Comment: Also, we don't have access to `cs50.h`, so please remove `string` and such and replace it with `char *` or whatever it's defined as.

Comment: @FiddlingBits - This is a class that unfortunately uses `cs50`.  Asking OP to remove `string` etc. would be like asking you to create a usable `char **buffer = {0}; without using `malloc()`.

Comment: What do you mean by `blank letters above key 10`?

Comment: @ryyker What I'm saying is, change `string` to `char *`, or whatever it's defined as, at least for SO.

Comment: @FiddlingBits -   I understand, but I do not know if OP would even know how to make those conversions at this point, i.e. stated experience is _just started cs50_ afterall.

Comment: Would `isalnum(s[i])` be better than `isdigit(s[i])`

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is, on your machine, `char` is a signed 8-bit value.  The maximum value is `127`.  `'z'` has a value of `122` (in ASCII).  Adding `6 + n` to it would result in `128 + n`, but since it cannot hold that value, it overflows.  When a signed integer overflows, it results in undefined behavior.

You need to check for overflow.  One way would be to convert `char` to a type that can hold a larger value.  For example:

```
int c = text[i];
c += key;
while(c > 'z')
    c -= 26;
text[i] = c;
```

You would have to do something similar for capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are allowed to, but you could try to get the input character by character and encipher it. You are getting "blank keys" or random symbols, because a char variable ranges from -128 and 127. Assuming that your input is **'x'** , and your *key* is **13**, your enciphered character will have a value of **133** , since *ASCII* value of **'x'** is *120*, which will result in `undefined behavior` . You can either set the input variable as an `unsigned char` or as `int` which can hold values greater than 127 (compiler dependent).

Code:

```
 int c=0,key=0,old_c=0;
  
 while ((c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n')
  {
    if ((c>='A'&&c<='Z')||(c>='a'&&c<='z'))
    {
      old_c=c;
      c+=key;
      while ((old_c<='Z'&&c>'Z')||(old_c<='z'&&c>'z'))
      {
        c-=26;
      }
    }
    if (c>=-128&&c<=127)
    {
      putchar(c);
    }
  }
```